# Как вытащить в select редактируемую марку авто по умолчанию?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть таблица с моделями и марками авто.

[image: таблица]

Для редактирования модели нажимаю "edit", выскакивает МОДУЛЬ редактирования модели:

[image: Модуль]

В полях показаны старые значения и фото авто. Все значения в модуль подставляются через AJAX. 
Проблема в том что он не может по умолчанию показать марку авто! В select стоит цикл, в котором показаны все марки авто. К примеру сейчас показана модель Ауди,а в поле показано Инфинити. Как это исправить?

1. Код edit'a:

   ```html
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit_link2" data-model_id="<?php echo $model['id'];?>" data-foto="<?php echo $model['photo'];?>" data-model_name="<?php echo $model['model_name'];?>" data-marka_name="<?php echo $marka['marka_name']; ?>" data-model_op="<?php echo $model['opisanie'];?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">edit</a>
   ```
2. Код замены AJAX:

   ```html
   <script>
     $(".edit_link2").click(function() {
       var model_id=$(this).data('model_id');
       var foto=$(this).data('foto');
       var marka_name=$(this).data('marka_name');
       var model_name=$(this).data('model_name');
       var model_op=$(this).data('model_op');
       $('#model_id').val(model_id);
       $('#marka_id3').val(marka_name);
       $('#opisanie').val(model_op);
       $('#foto').attr('src','../uploads/'+foto);
       $('#model3').val(model_name);
     });
   </script>
   ```
3. Модуль редактирования:

   ```html
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">    
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" id="zakryvalka3" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">
             <b>Редактирование модели <?php echo $marka['marka_name']; ?></b>
           </h4> 
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <form action="javascript:void(0)" onSubmit="edit_model(this)" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
             <input type="hidden" name="target" value="edit_model">
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="model">
                   <b>Выберите новую марку:</b>
                 </label><br>
                 <div class="col-sm-3">
                   <select name="marka_id" id="marka_id3" style="font-size:18;">
                     <?php while ($marka3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($marki3)):?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $marka3['id'];?>">
                         <?php echo $marka3['marka_name'];?>
                       </option>
                     <?php endwhile;?>
                   </select><br>
                 </div>
               </div>
         <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="model">
                   <b>Новое название:</b>
                 </label>
                 <div class="col-sm-7">
                   <input type="text" name="model_name" class="form-control" id="model3" value="<?php echo $model['model_name'];?>"><br>
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="model">
                   <b>Загрузите фото:</b>
                 </label>
                 <div class="col-sm-3">
                   <input type="file" name="photo_file"><br>
                   <img id="foto" src="../uploads/<?php echo $model['photo'];?>" width="400"><br/><br/>
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="opisanie">      
                   <br><b>Редактировать описание:</b>
                 </label>
                 <div class="col-sm-9">
                   <br><textarea name="opisanie" rows="20"  cols=8 class="form-control" id="opisanie"></textarea>
                 </div>
               </div>
         <input type="hidden" id="model_id" name="model_id" value="<?php echo $model['id'];?>">
               <div class="form-group">      
                 <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                     <b>Изменить</b>
                   </button>
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                   <a href="model.php?marka_id=<?php echo $marka_id;?>" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
                     <b>Назад</b>
                   </a><br><br>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </form>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   ```

Comment: В коде модуля нужный кусок отмечен сверху и снизу **

Comment: может, добавить к элементу еще один атрибут, например, назвав его default_car и туда писать значение по умолчанию...